# Is a falling tree basically a giant nutcracker?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, terminology, definition

When a tree falls, either cut down or because it’s roots can no longer hold it upright, does it behave as a giant nutcracker? It seems like it would, in which case I imagine standing near the base as it falls would be the worst place to stand, just as the fulcrum is the worst place to be inside a nutcracker. But on the other hand there isn’t a fixed fulcrum, at least not when the tree has been cut. When the roots can no longer hold it upright, I suppose they’re still exerting some force on it, and may be acting as a lose fulcrum? But on the other hand not every nutcracker-like lever has a fixed fulcrum, correct—-I believe the human jaw is a floating joint held together by muscles and connective tissues? So I’m at a loss as to the correct answer here: is a falling tree basically a giant nutcracker or not?

*Edit*: obviously dead is dead if a tree falls on you, but the answer to the question could still matter if for example a tree falls on a car or a house, something a little more sturdy and better able to withstand a tree. Then the question at hand implies the best and worst place to be with respect to the base of the tree.

Edit 2: I think I meant a second class lever—a giant nutcracker. I’ve edited the title and question to reflect this.

Comment: Yes and yes.  :)

Comment: What sparked this question for me was considering that besides their massive weight, perhaps part of what makes having a tree fall on something so devastating is that it is (maybe) a class three lever, so the force of its fall is made even worse than it would be if the object has the misfortune of being near the base of the tree? I dunno, just one of those thoughts that leads to a question on SO.

Comment: Deleted my comments after you changed the title and added information to clarify what you really were asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends entirely on what you consider the “effort” and what you consider the “load.” For folks like me  who have forgotten the classes of levers, they are

1. Load and effort on different sides of the fulcrum. A force-direction-reverser, like a seesaw.
2. Load closer to the fulcrum than the effort. A force-amplifier, like a nutcracker.
3. Load further from the fulcrum than the effort. A distance-amplifier, like a broom pushing dust.

I think you are imagining an incompetent lumberjack trying to prevent the tree from falling as the “effort,” and the weight of the tree as the “load.” But given the effects of your thought experiment, it seems more natural to think of the tree as the “cause” and the squashed lumberjack as the “effect.” In that case, your nutcracker scenario is a second-class lever.  The third-class scenario, in which the tree’s crown whips past a person as the tree falls, wouldn’t be a picnic either.

I have recently seen, in the sewer of internet “fail videos,” a falling tree which separated from its stump mid-fall. The trunk kicked backwards, went between the legs of an incompetent lumberjack who should have been standing somewhere else, and launched the poor fellow several meters into the air as the bulk of the tree fell. That is a class-one lever, so we’ve covered all the bases.

Comment: I had the class wrong: I meant class 2, a giant nutcracker.